# Python 3.4 Inheritance

Tags: python-3.x

I have a medical form class. This form would be given to both male and female. I would like NOT to have to differentiate between male and female when I instantiate the class. It would  be nice if I could instantiate the same way regardless of the gender and ask same questions regardless of  the gender. But the program which  will realize it is stupid to ask if a man is pregnant, then it will either not ask that question or better yet print saying it is irrelevant question and skip it.
This is basic code I have.

```
if male:
  form = medForm("Bill")
  form.MedHistory.isSmoking()


if female:
  form = medForm("Sarah")
  form.MedHistory.isSmoking()
  form.MedHistory.isPregnent()


class maleSection():
  def isSmoking(self):
     #some code here exactly same as female, so create a base class later

class femaleSection():
  def isPregnent(self):
     #some code here

  def isSmoking(self):
     #some code here exactly same as male, so create a base class later

class medForm(maleSection, femaleSection):
   def _init_(self, nameOfCustomer):
      #At the moment not sure if I need anything here
```

Those two if statements are ugly. Whats the best way to handle this? Also I heard using Super can be tricky, therefore, if possible I would like to not use Super and keep it simple. This is being run on Win7, Python 3.4. sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: First: install Python 3.6 and go fromt here if possible - no reason to go with old versions

Comment: Secon: there is nothing tricky about using  `super` - not using it is _much_ trickier.  Don't try to avoid it.

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I cant upgrade, too many dependencies. If you could give me an example with super on how to solve my issue, it would be really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of problem, the best approach is to utilize inheritance. It saves you a lot of time, especially if you need to change something later.

Try something like this:

```
    class patientSection():
        def isSmoking(self):
            #the code here is the same for both male and female

    class maleSection(patientSection):
        #no code here, since we have access to isSmoking already

    class femaleSection(patientSection):
        #again, we have access to isSmoking
        def isPregnant(self):
            #something here
```

You can declare an instance of just a patientSection if you want to ask only gender neutral questions; however, you'll need to use femaleSection to utilize the isPregnant method.

Comment: A. McKernan that't the difference between a problem and a problem solver. Thank you very much for help. I was really hoping Python may have a some slik way to figure this out.

Comment: @usustarr no problem, I am happy I could help! Good luck!